# ExpressJS - Regex for matching a path doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I have a simple regex that should match words made of letters (0-5) only however it doesn't seems to be working. How should the regex look and be used in ExpressJS? URL I am trying to validate may look like `something.com/abcd`

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();

app.get("/:id(^[a-z]{0,5}$)", function(req, res) {
    res.send("The right path!");
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set up an URL which accepts `/` followed by up to five ascii characters, you could do like this:

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express();

app.get("/[a-z]{0,5}$", function(req, res){
    res.send("Right path!");
});
app.listen(8000);
```

result:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/
Right path!

GET http://localhost:8000/abcde
Right path!

GET http://localhost:8000/abcdef
Cannot GET /abcdef
```

**Note:** Express does [case insensitive routing by default.](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings) To change it, put this at the top of your script:

```
app.set('case sensitive routing', true);
```

Now, `[a-z]` will match only lower case characters: `GET /abc` but not `GET /ABC`

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question what If I want accept queries only with a-c (lowercase)? I thought that it will work like that ,but it doesn't... I don't know regex very well.

Comment: Change `[a-z]` into `[a-c]` and it will only accept characters `a`, `b` and `c`

Comment: Sorry I made mistake I didn't want to write a-c I thought a-z ,but only lower case not somethig like /aBcd.

Comment: You are right, Express treats all urls as case insensitive by default. I will edit my post

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear:
The original question is the valid syntax to match an express.js route in a

> NAMED paramter

The only error is to have the start/end anchors within the RegExp.
I think they are added automatically.

[A nice tool to validate express routes](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) says this is fine:

`/:id([a-z]{0,5})`

btw: To whoever downvoted the question: shame on you.

I would strongly suggest to use the "named param" syntax because 
[app.param](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/13/parameterized-routes-express-js/) is a nice feature.

Comment: I typed in route=/:id/? and path=/5 and it says the path doesn't match the route...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what app.get does, but if we are speaking about regular expressions:

^ can be situated at the first position. It means that need to compare string from beginning.
Or, in [^\d] block, this means inversion, in this case this is any symbol except number.

remove ^ symbol

Comment: It works ,but when I enter /aDcd it is correct. Shouldn't be this regex only for lowercase letters?